# Jquery breaks when I load an Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, append, break

I am loading an iframe into a page and the jquery on that page breaks and no longer works.  Is there a reason for this?

I have jquery being called in the iframe, but even if I take out the jquery call, the parent frame's jquery still doesn't work.

The iframe is from a different domain and everything in the iframe works (all the js and jquery) but any jquery in the parent frame no longer works.

Iframe is being added to the parent using javascript:

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML + '<iframe src=""></iframe>';
```

Thanks

Comment: You should really do this instead: `$("body").append("<iframe src=''>");`

Comment: I'm betting this works in some browser but not others. Try Derek's suggestion.

Comment: Jquery isn't in every page that the iframe is on.  That is why I went with the basic javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Struggled on this for some time, unable to find an answer. Indeed when you do a `document.body.innerHTML +=` and insert an iframe for some reason jQuery will stop working without any errors.

If you first create a div and add it with `document.body.appendChild(elemDiv)`, you can then add the iframe with `elemDiv.innerHTML = "<iframe`

Hope this helps someone else.

Cheers,
Sam